# Relaying Wifi over the Internet

Tags: wireless-networking, vlan

I have two consumer devices with WiFi: A and B, where A is an access point and B is a client. They are black boxes, we can't configure them, but they work with each other great in WiFi range.

The problem is, I'm putting them at completely different locations and I want them to remain connected. So I'd like to set up some sort of a relay over the internet with, I'm guessing, an additional client (X) and an AP (Y), so A and B think they are talking to each other directly.

```
A <--wifi--> X <===internet===> Y <---wifi---> B
```

I don't even know what terms I should google. Am I tunneling WiFi over VLAN? Bridging? Relaying? Obviously we need to preserve SSID and so forth.

How do I approach this problem?

X and Y can be any consumer Linux devices that we fully control - an OpenWRT router, a laptop, whatever.

Comment: It might help if you could tell us more about what these two devices do together, besides being a Wi-Fi AP and client. For example, let's say the client is a security camera and the AP is a fancy DVR that records the video stream from the security camera. That video stream probably goes over TCP/IP (or maybe UDP/IP), so there's probably a way to make sure that TCP connection or UDP stream can reach the DVR from the camera even if they are on separate IP subnets across the public Internet from each other.

Answer (score 2):

It's some kind of a tunnel.

However, there is no need to tunnel "Wi-Fi" specifically, because all that Wi-Fi does is provide access to an Ethernet-like (well, 802.3-like) network, and client devices *pretend* they're speaking Ethernet over it, anyway.

And by design, Wi-Fi already supports multiple "access points" broadcasting the same SSID if they're simply attached to the same Ethernet segment – this is very commonly used in larger installations.

Therefore X&Y can just be independent Wi-Fi access points and all you need to tunnel is Ethernet frames. It's commonly called a "L2 VPN" (due to Ethernet being at layer-2).

A Linux system will have *plenty* of mechanisms for L2 tunnels – Tinc in 'switch' mode; GRE-tap; VXLAN; ZeroTier; L2TP; OpenVPN in 'tap' mode; just to name a few. All of these methods result in a virtual "Ethernet-like" interface on X&Y, such as tap0.

Once the tunnel is running, use standard Linux tools to bridge this tunnel interface with the physical one. (**Note:** This means X&Y must have two network interfaces, uplink and downlink – although they don't necessarily have to be wired Ethernet ports.

For example, if X&Y are OpenWRT or RasPi devices with internal Wi-Fi, you can bridge the tunnel with the Wi-Fi interface. Same with just about anything that supports `hostapd` for AP mode. And if you use VLANs, you can bridge the tunnel with a VLAN too. It all depends on the situation.)

Comment: grawity, thank you for a detailed answer. However I don't quite understand the alternative in the last paragraph, i.e. WiFi vs VLAN (?), since they work on a different level. Maybe to narrow the discussion, let me add some requirements: 1) X needs to have a small footprint, so it's likely an OpenWRT mobile router or an RPi. 2) For extra credit, it would be nice if I could analyze the traffic going through Y for some insight into the black boxes. (So Y is probably a laptop with wireshark etc, pretending to be A for B, with wifi in AP mode.)

Comment: They work at _nearly_ the same level, because both carry Ethernet-like payloads inside. (The whole point of VLANs, after all, is to substitute for multiple physical Ethernet cables.) It is very common for a Wi-Fi access point to receive several Ethernet VLANs and broadcast them as independent Wi-Fi SSIDs.

Comment: grawity, would it be beneficial if one could establish if the devices in question may be running comms at a higher level, like ip, either through specs (need to know what devices) or trace (need AP with trace ability)? No benefit? Or is ip highly unlikely for these assumed devices? @Qrious it would help if you could edit your question to include the type of devices.